# Jar file cannot read the sqlite database file

Tags: java, sqlite, javafx, jar

I am creating a **JavaFX** application with some read and writes to **sqlite database**.

I created the connection to the database file using,

`connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");` and I placed the database file in project root.

Once I run the project it works as expected. But when I build the jar file and run the file, the application closes when I try to query from the database. Placing the `db` file in the directory of `jar` file doesn't work. I think the problem is with storing the database file or the method of reading the database file. I already looked at [Github page for sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/Usage.md#reading-database-files-in-classpaths-or-network-read-only) and it says about some read-only method of saving the file. But it doesn't make sense to me.

So I am very grateful if anyone can guide me in this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found a solution. I tried the method on [Github sqlite-jdbc](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/blob/master/Usage.md#reading-database-files-in-classpaths-or-network-read-only) and it didn't work. It turned out that I had to manually create a resource folder and add it as a resource folder in the project settings of **Intellij Idea IDE**. Then I had to define the connection as

`connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:test.db");`

and put the **db** file inside the resources folder. The method of adding the resource folder is different from IDE to IDE. When the project is run, it automatically identifies the resource folder and the system will bundle the **database file** inside the **jar file**.